# verilog generate instantiating modules

Tags: verilog

Does anyone know how to instantiate the following module, using the generate command, multiple times?

```
    module osc
         (
             input wire [7:0] osc_i,
             output reg [7:0] osc_o
         );

         always @(osc_i) osc_o = osc_i;
    endmodule
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate of [instantiate-n-times-a-given-module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/32446/13513).

But the basic syntax for Verilog 2001 and above is :

```
genvar i;
generate 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) begin
    myModule instance();
  end
endgenerate
```